# Child div with absolute position parent

Tags: html, css

The `<p>` child of a `position:absolute` div is arranging so that it appears to be attaching to the top left of the `absolute` parent div (below image showing output from chrome inspector).

[image: child and absolute div]

As I understand it, the child should be within the 'flow' of the parent div, and so should be within the confines of the parent div.

CSS is:

```
.modal{
    position:fixed;
    width:auto;
    height:100px;
    left:50%;
    top:75%;
    z-index:52;
    background-color: #2a333c;
}

.modal p{
    position:relative;
}
```

HTML is:

```
<div class="modal">
<p>new user template</p>
</div>
```

NB The greying effect is caused by another `fixed` div that is alongside the `absolute` modal div with a lower `z-index` value, but is neither parent nor child of the 'modal' div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As I understand it, the child should be within the 'flow' of the parent div, and so should be within the confines of the parent div.

Yes, and [all else being equal, it will be](http://jsfiddle.net/RkVSg/).

Other style rules can influence its position though.

Comment: It was an inherited set of negative margins from my bootstrap css.